# Algorithm bound analysis and using integrals

Tags: algorithm, math, analysis

I am supposed to get a lower and an upper bound of an alogrithm using integrals, but I don't understand how to do that. I know basic integration principles but I don't know how to figure out the integral from the algorithm.

**Problem:**

- My first for loop starts at i = 5n ---> and goes to 6n cubed,

  - the next one inside would be starting at j=5 ---> and going to i,

    - then the final next for loop would be starting at k=j and going to i.

Naturally, my first step was to turn this into 3 summations. So I have my 3 summations set up and what I'm wanting to do is simplify these to just one summation if possible. That way if I have some variables to the right of my summation I can now take the integral.

In terms of the bounds I'm using for my integral, from Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen, Leiserson, etc. you can do approximation by integrals.

**Nature of the integrals**:

- For the upper bound your bounds of the integral may be: upper bound n+1, lower bound m.
- For the lower bound your bounds of your integral may be: upper bound n, lower bound m-1.

I want to know how to simplify my three summations into one if possible. If things are to one summation I can start to take the integral and go from there myself.

This is *very* rough pseudo code, but I tried my best to make it look similar to actual code.

```
for(i = 5n; i<6n^3; i++)
{
    for(j =5; j<i; j++)
    {
        for(k=j; k < i; k++)
        {
            i - j + k;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please calrify more, the current explanation is not informative enough. A loop that goes from i=5n to "6n cubed" is not saying nothing without knowing how `i` behaves between iterations. Can you post a code sample?

Comment: Okay, I tried my best to make it look like actual code. All of this is just very confusing right now.

Comment: Your post is difficult to read because of code instead of text formatting in the first several paragraphs.  Don't indent ordinary text with so many spaces that it turns on code formatting.  Please edit your question and fix it

Comment: Sorry about that, I just edited it to the way it should be.

Comment: I've never formally studied algorithm analysis, but it appears to me that a good upper bound might be {i[1,6n^3], j[i,6n^3], k[1,6n^3]}, if you see what I mean. I'll see if I can find a lower one...

Comment: `i - j + k;` This looks wrong. What is it supposed to read?

Comment: Further, you say `"6n cubed"`, is that `(6n)^3` or `6n^3`? Please update your post with the necessary information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let any of `int(i,j,f)` or `int(x=i,j,f(x))` or `∫(x=i,j,f(x))` denote the definite integral of `f(x)` as x ranges from i to j.  If `f(x)` is the amount of work done (by a program) when x has a particular value, and if f is a monotonically increasing function, then as you point out in the question, `int(m,n+1,f)` is an upper bound, and  `int(m+1,n,f)` a lower bound, on the work done as x takes the values `m...n`.  In following, I will say that `int(m,n,f)` approximates the work, and you can add `+1` terms where appropriate to get  upper and lower bounds. Note, 6n^3-1 stands for 6*(n^3)-1, 5n for 5*n, etc.

Approximate work is:
`int(i=5n, 6n^3-1, u(i))`
where `u(i)` is
`int(j=5, i-1, v(i,j))` 
where `v(i,j)` is
`int(k=j, i-1, w(k))`
where `w(k)` is 1.  In following we use functions p, q, r to stand for indefinite integrals, and C for constants of integration that cancel out for definite integrals.

Let `r(x) = ∫1dx = x + C`.
Now `v(i,j) = ∫(k=j, i-1, 1) = r(i-1)-r(j) = i-1-j`.

Let `q(x,i) = ∫(i-1-x)dx = x*(i-1)-x*x/2 + C`.
Now `u(i) = ∫(j=5, i-1, i-1-j) = q(i-1,i)-q(5,i)`
which is some quadratic in `i`.  You will need to work out the details for the upper and lower bound cases.

Let `p(x) = ∫u(x)dx = ∫(q(x-1,x)-q(5,x))`,
which is some cubic in x. The overall result is
`p(6n^3-1)-p(5n)`
and again you will need to work out the details.  But note that when `6n^3-1` is substituted for x in p(x), the order is going to be `(6n^3-1)^3`, that is, O(n^9), so you should expect upper and lower bound expressions that are O(n^9).  Note, you can also see the  O(n^9) order by inspecting your loops:  In `for(i=5n; i<6n^3; i++)`, i will average about `3n^3`.  In `for(j =5; j<i; j++)`, j will average about i/2, or some small multiple of n^3.  In `for(k=j; k < i; k++)`, `k-j` also will average a small multiple of n^3.  Thus, expression `i-j+k` will be evaluated some small multiple of n^3*n^3*n^3, or n^9, times.